# Android: how to use adb commands to block/unblock specific app from using the Internet, on rooted device if needed?

Tags: linux, firewall, adb

### Background

I want to temporarily block a specific app from using the Internet on my Android device, using a batch file. The device is rooted, so it should be possible via the PC.

### The problem

I actually found something over the Internet that seems to work fine for most apps:

```
@echo off
set package_name="com.android.chrome"

c:
cd\
cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('adb shell dumpsys package %package_name% ^| findstr "userId="') do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%B in ("%%A") do (
    echo Extracted UID: %%B
    adb shell "su -c 'iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner %%B -j DROP'"
  )
)
```

And to unblock:

```
@echo off
set package_name="com.android.chrome"

c:
cd\
cd C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('adb shell dumpsys package %package_name% ^| findstr "userId="') do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %%B in ("%%A") do (
    echo Extracted UID: %%B
    adb shell "su -c 'iptables -D OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner %%B -j DROP'"
  )
)
```

Thing is, as I wrote, it doesn't always work for all apps.

I also tried this instead:

```
...
adb shell "su -c 'iptables -I OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner %%B -j REJECT'"
```

### What I've found

I've found an open sourced app called "[AFWall+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dev.ukanth.ufirewall)" , and inside of it, I've noticed a file that seems to call many functions to block the app. When launching the app and applying a blocking rule, it indeed takes some time, which means maybe it's worth checking out:

https://github.com/ukanth/afwall/blob/beta/app/src/main/java/dev/ukanth/ufirewall/Api.java#L660

I've tried to launch it and debug, and I think it created more than 90 adb commands in the process of blocking a single app that I chose...

But, it seems it worked.

### The questions

1. Is there a minimal way to block an app completely from the Internet using adb ?
2. How come there are so many commands that were used on "AFWall+"?

Comment: "*it doesn't always work for all apps.*" perhaps you might want to clarify *what* doesn't work. I'd assume that the internet blocking doesn't work, not the command doesn't register, but a clarification won't hurt.

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't know the cause of it. I just noticed that the Android app somehow succeeded to communicate. Or at least it seems this way. I have tried to explain all that I've tried... I just want to know if there is a better command/s to do it. Perhaps I'm missing here something.